# Color of bar in chart based off boolean value in the same row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm Trying to construct a bar chart with the colour of the bars being influenced from the boolean value on the same row in the dataframe. In this example I'm wanting `has_chocolate` with `False` to be red and `True` to be green when `sales` are put in a bar chart.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
cake_sales_df

index     cake          sales          has_chocolate
0         empire        15             False
1         tea cake      25             True
2         snowball      20             True
3         hob-nob       50             True
4         lotus         3              False
```

What I've attempted so far with using an outside function or a condition

```
cake_sales_df.plot(x='cake', y='sales',
                        kind='bar', color = 'green' if cakes_sales_df['has_chocolate'] == True else 'red')
```

have all gotten me the same error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pivot the data:

```
(df.pivot(index='cake',columns='has_chocolate',values='sales')
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Or you can use seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(data=df, x='cake', y='sales', hue='has_chocolate',
            palette={True:'g', False:'r'},
            dodge=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I'm still novice at this and seaborn is still something I'm still to bring into my skills.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use matplotlib to make a bar chart. But due to the lack of reputation the picture is not embedded. Instead the links to imgur are provided.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

columns = ['cake', 'sales', 'has_chocolate']
df = pd.DataFrame([['empire', 15, False],['tea cake',25, True],['snowball', 20, True],['hob-nob', 50, True],['lotus', 3, False]], columns = columns).set_index('cake')
df
```

[data in jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF8Rd.png)

```
colours = {True: "#44bd32", False: "#273c75"}
df['sales'].plot(
    kind="bar", 
    color=df['has_chocolate'].replace(colours)
).legend(
    [   Patch(facecolor=colours[True]),
        Patch(facecolor=colours[False])
    ], [True, False]
)
```

[the bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mXBy.png)